# PowerQuery to convert a Record into text

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Here's something I am needing to do. I am looking to convert a Record into `Text/string` representation.

**For example:-**

if a record is

> [OrderId = "10001", Owner = "Sam"]

I would like to convert it into a text format like this:

> "[OrderId = \"10001\", Owner = \"Sam\"]"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, works for any # of fields

```
let x=[OrderId = "10001", Owner = "Sam"] ,
z="""["&Text.Combine(Table.AddColumn(Record.ToTable(x), "Custom", each [Name]&" = \"""&[Value])[Custom],"\"", ")&"\""]"""
in z
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WivYvSkkt8kxRsFWIUTI0MDAwjFHSUfAvz0stAgsFJ+bGKMUqxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Record = _t]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Record", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("""", QuoteStyle.None), {"Record.1", "Record.2", "Record.3", "Record.4", "Record.5"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Custom", each Character.FromNumber(34) 
& [Record.1] 
& "\" & Character.FromNumber(34) 
&[Record.2]
& "\" & Character.FromNumber(34) 
&[Record.3]
& "\" & Character.FromNumber(34) 
&[Record.4]
& "\" & Character.FromNumber(34) 
& [Record.5]
& Character.FromNumber(34))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

if the record comes as below , it is another question...

| OrderID | Owner |
| --- | --- |
| 100001 | Sam |

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, it is not a hardcoded value of 2 fields. There could be more. In that case, is it possible to loop over instead of splitting the record into 5 parts?

Comment: @NikhilPNaik you can adjust this code and use it as long as the data structure (columns) does not change...

Comment: @NikhilPNaik you'd better send the exact columns with sample data and expected result while asking a question...

Comment: My bad, I didn't explicitly specify that the fields are dynamic. Nonetheless, thanks for your help!